# Why can't I access VALUE or DATA with jQuery Autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I'm using this jQuery Autocomplete and on the whole it's working great:
https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

I'm struggling with the callback function though upon the user selecting from the options:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control vrm" id="type-autocomplete" />

<script type="text/javascript">
// Create autocomplete:
$('#type-autocomplete').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl:'autocomplete.php?searchtype=product',
    noCache: true,
    delimiter: /(,|;)\s*/, // regex or character
    onSelect: function(value, data){ alert('You selected: ' + value + ', ' + data); },
}); 
</script>
```

The alert I get is:

> You selected: [object Object], undefined

I really need the use the "data" part to populate some hidden form fields. Any ideas what's up please?

EDIT:

I had followed the integration guide here which seems out of date with github:
http://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/

This code is now working:

```
onSelect: function(suggestion){ alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data); },
```

Comment: [Read the documentation](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete#usage), it spells out an example of what you should be doing. Also, `console.log(value)` should display the object in your debugging console instead of converting it to a string.

Comment: Arh see my edit. I shoud have followed github from the start, the the original URL I've just added to my EDIT. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [**docs**](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete#usage):

```
 onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
    }
```

Comment: Whilst I'm here - if I have used urlencode() on some of the PHP variables in my ajax request... do you know how I decode them on the frontend as my spaces are now pluses?

Comment: I have no idea I am not a php geek